# HOC useEffect firing before Authentication Context ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have an Authentication Context that uses `useEffect` for getting data from sessionStorage and set a global `user` variable to pass down via context api.

On each protected route, I have a `useEffect` inside my hoc to check if the user is logged, and if it isn't send the user back to login page.

However, the `useEffect` inside the hoc is firing before the Authentication Context and therefore, doesn't see the authentication data and sends the customer to login page every time

```
  const router = useRouter()

  const [ user, setUser ] = useState(null)
  const [ loading, setLoading ] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    async function loadUserFromSessionStorage() {
      const token = sessionStorage.getItem('accessToken')
      if (token) {
        const { data: { customer: { name } } } = await axios.get(`http://localhost:3002/customer/token/${token}`)
        if (name) setUser(name)
      }
      setLoading(false)
    }

    loadUserFromSessionStorage()
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    if(!!user) router.push('/')
  }, [ user ])

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{ isAuthenticated: !!user, loading, user}}
    >
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

And this is my HOC:

```
  return () => {
    const { user, isAuthenticated, loading } = useContext(AuthContext);
    const router = useRouter();
    useEffect(() => {
      if (!isAuthenticated && !loading){
        router.push("/login")
      }
      
    }, [ loading, isAuthenticated ]);

    return (
      isAuthenticated && <Component {...arguments} />
    )
  };
}
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you may or may not know, the useEffect hook in your HOC will fire before the hook that loads your user from session state completes.

Where you went wrong is in  setting your loading state to false by default:

```
const [ loading, setLoading ] = useState(false)
```

When you do this in the HOC effect hook

```
if (!isAuthenticated && !loading)...
```

That expression will be true the first time through and you get redirected to the login page. Just do useState(true) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You're not passing the `loading` variable into the context, so when you deconstruct the context value in your HOC, it looks like:

```
{
    user: undefined,
    isAuthenticated: false,
    loading: undefined
}
```

which, based on your logic will redirect to login.

Try adding the other two variables inside your `AuthContext.Provider` and see if that helps you out.

Comment: I have included the missing variables but still no success.. Even when I console.log() it always logs the HOC useEffect first. This is probably the main cause. I need AuthContext useEffect() to fire first, get the credentials and then when I call ProtectRoute(Home) it verifies that I am logged.

Comment: how about using a default value of `true` here, as well: `const [ loading, setLoading ] = useState(false)`

Comment: Thank you, DMac. I believe that will solve my problem